# General formulation of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I would like some clarification on how to define general tensor products. Coming from a physics background, tensor products are introduced only in the case of finite dimensional vector space for the sake of single particle quantum mechanics.

Unfortunately even in the case of QM we encounter infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces and this is treated in a rather hand-waving manner. So I would like to understand the tensor product in the general case. The basic definition that I was introduced to is:

Suppose $V , W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. Then we define the space $ V \otimes W$ as the space of linear maps $L: V \times W \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the underlying field of $V$ and $W$. Since we required elements of $V \otimes W$ to be linear, I would guess that we require a similar definition with "linear" being replaced by "structure-preserving" for a general algebraic structure?

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of monoidal categories?

Comment: @Matthias I'm aware of the concept but I wouldn't say I'm familiar with it. I have a very surface level understanding of category theory. If there is a category theoretic generalization I'd gladly accept that as an answer

Comment: This definition is found in some sources but it is incorrect. The correct definition can be found e.g. on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: And for Hilbert spaces see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces